# AAC+ Streaming from shoutcast in Flash

Tags: flash, audio-streaming, aac+

I'm trying to stream a AAC+ shoutcast URL like this one http://live7.avf.ch:8000/ipmusicaacplus32 with flash AS3 but it won't work. If I put a .m4a file instead of the streaming URL it works.
Any idea why the shoutcast URL doesn't work?

```
var connect_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
connect_nc.connect(null);
var stream_ns:NetStream = new NetStream(connect_nc);
stream_ns.play("http://live7.avf.ch:8000/ipmusicaacplus32");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoutcast AAC is packaged completely differently to MPEG4 containers used by .m4a etc. Flash doesn't understand the ADTS packaging that Shoutcast AAC uses. The end. Give up.

...or IIRC, [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) can repackage the stream so that Flash Netstream can consume it.