# Is it possible to play AAC provided by SHOUTcast with HTML5?

Tags: html, flash, audio, aac, shoutcast

I tried the following code below:

```
<audio src="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/;" controls autoplay></audio>
```

I'm using Mac and this code worked fine with Safari but not with Chrome or Firefox.

Is there any solution using only HTML5? If not, can I make a fallback with some Flash open source library? How?

Comment: i think u want to point at the m3u file.

Comment: @j_mcnally Like `/stream.m3u`? It doesn't work. :(

Comment: o yeah only some browsers support AAC. Safari makes sense, but its possible chrome dropped support.

Comment: can you offer and ogg stream and also a mp3 stream. The combination of those with the proper tag should support all browsers.

Comment: @j_mcnally That is incorrect.  The playlist file should not be used in an `<audio>` tag.  You are correct about the codec support however.

Comment: Really? I assumed for all html5 streaming you used a playlist since you are dynamically writing segments to a playlist. it must be different for audio than video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some third party audio player for aac but I will share some links on my vast search I did

1 - [HE AAC support](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25497)

As per this post and also [wiki pedia HEAAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding)

It says chrome supports HE-AAC

and here is a stack overflow post that will I guess help you to move formward.

[SO AAC support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018596/aac-streaming-from-shoutcast-in-flash)

And here is another link saying chrome supports 
**The MP4 container format with the H.264 video codec and either the AAC audio codec or the MP3 audio codec is natively supported by Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but Chromium and Opera do not support the format. Firefox will soon support the format, but only when a third-party decoder is available.

The MPEG media formats are covered by patents, which are not freely licensed. All the necessary licenses can be bought from MPEG LA. Since H.264 is currently not a royalty free format, it is unfit for the open web platform, according to Mozilla [1, 2], Google [1, 2] and Opera. However, since royalty free formats are not supported by Internet Explorer and Safari, Mozilla has decided to support the format anwyay, and Google never fulfilled their promise to remove support for it in  Chrome.**

LINK : [AAC Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements)

Please let me know if any of the link is help ful

Comment: Thank you. Until now you had the best answer. But I still search for an open source Flash fallback.

Comment: Did i get the bount if yes it did not add :p never mind still happy to help .

Comment: Ok i got that long ago sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

No AAC is only supported by Safari and Internet Explorer. Here is a list for audio file support.

> - IE - MP3, AAC
> - Chrome - OGG, MP3, WAV
> - Firefox - OGG, WAV
> - Safari - MP3, AAC, WAV
> - Opera - OGG, WAV

I assume that listeners are using the latest versions of each browser.

You can create a WAV and a AAC stream and provide the AAC if listener is using IE with html if-else hacks. But this solution is costly.

Comment: I don't like the "WAV" solution. I believe, in this case, the best solution is providing Flash fallback, like "JW player", but it isn't open source.

Comment: You could try jPlayer as an alternative. It's open source and has wide support for audio formats and browsers.

http://www.jplayer.org/

Comment: Thank you, but jPlayer don't support AAC.

Comment: AAC is served with .m4r, .3gp, .mp4, .aac extensions, feel free to use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. With Chrome, try using a video tag instead of an audio one:

```
<video controls="controls" width="100%" height="60px">
   <source src="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
   Your browser does not support video.
</video>
```

The only issue is that the Play/Stop controls hides automatically.